# Como soluciono este error en C++

Tags: c++

Hola buenas noches he estado intentado arreglar este error y sin embargo no lo he conseguido

```
  #include "iostream"

  #include "stdio.h"

  using namespace std;

 int main()

 {

     int coin=0;
     cout<<"============================"<<endl;
     cout<<" ¿ALGORITMO QUE NUNCA GANARAS?"<<endl;
     cout<<"maquina tragamonedas"<<endl;
     cout<<"============================"<<endl;
     cout<<"insert coin: ";

     cin>>coin;cout<<" "endl;

     int conteo=9+coin;
     int a=1;
     int b=1;
     int c=1;

     cout<<"welcome to liar"<<endl;
     cout<<" "<<a<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<endl;
     cout<<"START: Gire la palanca u oprima un boton"<<endl;
     getchar();
     for(int x=0; x=conteo; x++)
     {
        if(coin==1)
     {
        getchar();
        cout<<"Girando..."<<endl;
        cout<<"============RESULTADO==========="<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<(a^x)<<" "<<b+x<<" "<<c*x<<" "<<endl;
    }
    }

  }
```

Comment: bueno el error se muestra en el compilador como: error expected ';' before 'endl'

Comment: y ese pertenece a la linea 14

Comment: el error que pertenece a la linea 28 dice recipe for traget 'main.o' failed

Comment: Agrega todos los errores a la pregunta. Si hacen referencia a una linea, por favor indica tambien cuales son las lineas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltaba un << despues de las comillas, aqui te dejo el codigo correcto. Un saludo

```
#include "iostream"

  #include "stdio.h"

  using namespace std;

 int main()

 {

     int coin=0;
     cout<<"============================"<<endl;
     cout<<" ¿ALGORITMO QUE NUNCA GANARAS?"<<endl;
     cout<<"maquina tragamonedas"<<endl;
     cout<<"============================"<<endl;
     cout<<"insert coin: ";

     cin>>coin;
     cout<<" "<<endl;

     int conteo=9+coin;
     int a=1;
     int b=1;
     int c=1;

     cout<<"welcome to liar"<<endl;
     cout<<" "<<a<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<endl;
     cout<<"START: Gire la palanca u oprima un boton"<<endl;
     getchar();
     for(int x=0; x=conteo; x++)
     {
        if(coin==1)
     {
        getchar();
        cout<<"Girando..."<<endl;
        cout<<"============RESULTADO==========="<<endl;
        cout<<" "<<(a^x)<<" "<<b+x<<" "<<c*x<<" "<<endl;
    }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias no lo había notado

Comment: Si este es el caso, la pregunta debe cerrarse como error tipografico. Esta clase de preguntas no ayuda a futuros usuarios ya que no resuelve un problema real ;)